# Nvidia Geforce GTX 860M video card not recognized by Linux

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, asus, hybrid-graphics

I have a new laptop by Asus Republic Of gamers.

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on this laptop but now there is a problem with the video card not being even recognized by the system.

In Bios there is no option to activate/deactivate the video card.

There are a lot of workarounds on the internet but none of them mention how to make the VGA Controller to recognize this video card. I guess if I manage to make this work everything else should be easy to follow.

```
lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:157d]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at ed400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

and

```
lspci | grep -i nvidia
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev ff)
```

and

```
lspci -v

...

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
    !!! Unknown header type 7f

...
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mixing things. You should not trust **any** article on the internet that the "VGA Controller recognizes a video card" or not.

You have two video controllers in your system, one is the integrated graphics controller of your CPU which is VGA compatible, the other is the nVidia GeForce one. New drivers for nVidia are supposed to support that board, so do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-311-updates
```

Comment: Does not seems to work. And If I go to additional drivers area I cannot see any NVida even if I have installed the 331 drivers earlier.

Comment: WARNING: You do not appear to have an NVIDIA GPU supported by the 340.46 NVIDIA Linux graphics driver installed in this system.  For further details, please see the appendix SUPPORTED NVIDIA GRAPHICS CHIPS in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com. -> GeForce 800M Series (Notebooks)
GeForce GTX 880M, GeForce GTX 870M, GeForce GTX 860M. SO it is something else...